# REPLACE or INSERT...ON DUPLICATE UPDATE with a condition for existing records

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 2 database servers with identical schema.
Basically, I have a crontab job (every minute) to fetch all new or updated records within last 2 minutes from database 1 to database 2.

Database 2 is a Mysql server.
(Database 1 is not mysql server.)

To make sure I have all the data, I use "replace-into" statement.

```
REPLACE INTO myTable (ID, Data, CreateTime, UpdateTime) VALUES ....
```

Normally, it works well.

However, there are too many connections to database 1. Occasionally, a fetching takes over a minute due to connection problem, which jammed with the fetching in the next minute. The data batch which is fetched in time T was put into database 2 later than the batch in time T+1. Hence, a record with older data overwrite the newer one.

I want these to happen:

1. If the record is not exist in database 2, insert the records.
2. If the record exists in database 2, update the records **only if** createTime >= existing createTime or updateTime >= existing updateTime. (*If both createTime and updateTime are same as the existing ones, it is ok to overwrite the current records.)

The above replace-into can be rewritten into `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE UPDATE`, but my main problem is I need a where-condition to control the updating.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should try to use MySQL replication for this, instead of rolling your own.

Comment: Database 1 is not mysql. There are a lot records (4K every batch). Hence I cannot really use replication.